# C#: How get the actual type from Type variable

Tags: c#, .net, types, reflection

Given the `Type type` parameter,
How can I create the dictionary:
`Dictionary<Type, DataCollection<T>>`, where where `typeof(T) == type` ?

I tried `Dictionary<Type, DataCollection<Type>>`, but it doesn't work because
`DataCollection<T>` accepts data of type `T` (where `typeof(T) == type`), not of type `Type`.

Also, I cannot make it generic:
`Dictionary<T, DataCollection<T>>`
because I want all types to be accepted, not just a single type `T`

Comment: What does "Also, I cannot make it generic: Dictionary<T, DataCollection> because I want all types to be accepted, not just a single type T" mean?

Comment: What do you mean by `typeof(T) == Type`?

Comment: @Sweeper - That was my edit sweeper. I suspect I can improve it. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Enigmativity Ah, now I get it with the lowercase `type`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you pass an arbitrary type as the key at runtime, what would you expect to get as the value? Something unknown at compile-time. You either need to create a non-generic version of `DataCollection<T>` to use as the `TValue` or use reflection all the way.

Comment: Would it make sense to use a Non-Generic Wrapper for the value? Which just takes an `object` and has a generic _method_ `Get<T>()` ? Something like that? But then you can as well use a `Dictionary<T, object>` and cast ... hmmm

Comment: Generic types are evaluated statically. There is no such thing as generic only known at runtime types you can leverage while writing code; you will have to use reflection which basically makes the whole generic approach pointless. You are better off either going dynamic (and paying the type safety price) or going non-generic.

Comment: @InBetween - I feel reflection is better than `dynamic`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, It means that, if I have
Dictionary<Type, DataCollection<T>> d  = new Dictionary<Type, DataCollection<T>>();

to call for T t
d[typeof(T)].Add(t)
adding t of type T

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay
have a data of arbitrary type 
T t;
and add this data to the right DataCollection<T> in the dictionary
The dictionary key for this data is typeof(T)
Why this doesn't make sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because `T` must be known at compile time, so that the compiler can statically check your code. You are attempting to use heterogenous dictionary values, which would mean their type will only be known at runtime, depending on the key that is used. The compiler doesn't allow this because it isn't type safe. You need to refactor your code to be type safe, or do the type checking yourself i.e. using reflection / dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create the type with this:

```
Type type = typeof(int);
Type typeDC = typeof(DataCollection<>);

var t = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
var x = t.MakeGenericType(type, typeDC.MakeGenericType(type));

object o = Activator.CreateInstance(x);
```

You would then need to use reflection to call the methods of `o` or to pass `o` to a strongly-typed method.